# numpy flatten - how to print output

Tags: python, numpy, flatten

I need to turn array into vector. Here is my code.

```
from numpy import *
s1 = random.poisson(5,100).flatten
print(s1)
```

the output

```
<built-in method flatten of numpy.ndarray object at 0x0508DE80>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `flatten` is a method, call it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot parentheses.  You need to call the method.  You're only getting a handle to the method if you omit the parentheses:

```
s1 = random.poisson(5,100).flatten()
```

However, for completeness, you *can* do this... but probably shouldn't for code readability:

```
s1 = random.poisson(5,100).flatten
print(s1()) # <-- Calling the function
```

`s1` would contain the actual `flatten` method, and you can call it by doing `s1()`.

Comment: Wow! I did not know it is so easy to get a handle to the method. Thank you!

Comment: @user1700890 - no worries :)